# asp.net mvc 4 custom controller not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

in RouteConfig.cs i have custom controller route like this

```
routes.MapRoute("User", "user/{name}", new { controller = "User", action = "Index",name =""});
```

also i have Home controller with Index method

```
//
// GET: /User/

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Content("stinky");
}
```

also Index view for User controller

but when routing *localhost:11963/User/**

i getting error

***Server Error in '/' Application.***

Comment: does localhost:11963/User/Index work?

Comment: gives me error: Server Error in '/' Application.

Comment: en what is in the error? kinda hard to say like this

Comment: What are you trying to do?